# Oscommerce 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql-error-1064, oscommerce

Sure this has been asked before but I need help! My developer left me hanging with this error and I don't know how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from products_options where language_id = \'1\' order by products_optio' at line 1

select count(select * from products_options where language_id = \'1\' order by products_options_id) as total 1

[TEP STOP]

I get similar 1064 errors when I click on these links under catalog in the admin area below:
-Products Attributes
-Manufacturers
-Reviews
-Specials
-Featured Products
-Products Expected
-tags

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Count(*) AS total_1
   FROM Products_Options 
  WHERE language_id = 1
```

Comment: Also, you don't want to quote your "language_id" term, unless it is a char/varchar type in the underlying table.

Comment: thanks curt. i will run this in phpmyadmin and post the result